# Rcpp and default C++ compiler

Tags: r, macos, rcpp, clang++

I have some strange troubles with Rcpp - it uses unpredictable C++ compiler. This question is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr).
I'm on OSX, I have 2 complilers - default `clang` and `clang-omp` with openmp support.  Also I have following `~/.R/Makevars` file (where I set up `clang-omp` as default compiler):

> CC=clang-omp
>   CXX=clang-omp++
>   CFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99
>   CXXFLAGS += -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -fopenmp

The problem is that, the package I'm developing compiles with `clang++`, not `clang-omp++`. I also tried (as experiment to lacate issue) to change package `src/Makevars` and set `CXX=clang-omp++` and moreover modified `$R_HOME/etc/Makeconf` `CXX` entry to `CXX = clang-omp++`. No luck - it still compiles with `clang++`. Have no idea why it happens.

Also here is small reproducible (both from console R and from Rstudio) example (don't know whether it related to issue above).
Suppose 2 very similar cpp functions:
1.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

Call `sourceCpp` from R:

```
library(Rcpp)  
sourceCpp("src/Rcpp_compiler.cpp", verbose = T)
```

> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_1.so'  'Rcpp_compiler.cpp'
>   **clang-omp++** -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include  -I"/Users/dmitryselivanov/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/dmitryselivanov/projects/experiments/src"    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -fopenmp -c Rcpp_compiler.cpp -o Rcpp_compiler.o
>   **clang-omp++** -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_1.so Rcpp_compiler.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

**Work as expected - uses clang-omp++ and all my flags from `~/.R/Makevars`**

2.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}
```

> Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD SHLIB -o 'sourceCpp_2.so'  'Rcpp_compiler.cpp'
>   **clang++** -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include  -I"/Users/dmitryselivanov/Library/R/3.2/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/dmitryselivanov/projects/experiments/src"    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c Rcpp_compiler.cpp -o Rcpp_compiler.o
>   **clang++** -std=c++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_2.so Rcpp_compiler.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

**I only added `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` and it compiles with `clang++` instead of `clang-omp++`**

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

> R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
>   locale:
>   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr) en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>   attached base packages:
>   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>   other attached packages:
>   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr) Rcpp_0.12.1
>   loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr) tools_3.2.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks, to @Dirk hint, I finaly got an answer. Hope, this will save a little bit of time for somebody.
Following two lines in `~/.R/Makevars` solved my problem:

```
CXX1X=clang-omp++
```

**See details** in [this Writing R Extensions section](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code).

Comment: You will, of course, have no hope on earth of those kind of make flags making it on to CRAN. I have been through trying to use C++11 and OpenMP for a CRAN package, and found that you almost certainly need a 'configure' script.

Comment: Don't think, this is an issue. We can just add `C++11` to `SystemRequirements` and check omp support with `#ifdef _OPENMP ` macro. If it not supported - go with single thread. Anyway, yesterday, I rewrote all my concurrent parts with `RcppParallel` which is far more robust and far more portable - works even on Windows.

Comment: What is CXX1X ? The `Writing R Extensions` refers to CXX11 as a make variable directive to use C++11 compiler for the package. I'm looking for documentation that explains what CXX1X is but can only find info about CXX11, CXX14, CXX17.

Comment: This was changed since R 3.4. was CXX1X  before.

Answer (score -3):

I only read one line of your question and stopped there:

> I have some strange troubles with Rcpp - it uses unpredictable C++ compiler

That is both  **wrong** and also inflammatory.  Please read the R documentation included with your version of R and learn how R sets these things.

Rcpp does nothing extra.  All this is default R behaviour:

- As a user you can set this in `~/.R/Makevars`
- As a package author aiming for portable and CRAN-compatible packages you cannot but have to use, say, `configure` at package built-time.

This is all documented and has 
been discussed before.

Comment: As usual not very friendly response, but after digging another half of the day, I get solution. Will Accept your answer with my minor modifications which actually resolves my problem.

Comment: You could just come to rcpp-devel (or for this even r-package-devel as you have _packaging_ rather than Rcpp questions) and ask there.

Comment: If you now have an answer, feel free to add it or edit your question.  Good to see that why recommendation of checking "Writing R Extensions" was fruitful for you.

Comment: Is mailing list right place for such type of questions? Why not SO?