# Openmp decreases the running time in my Rcpp code, but not in my Rccp package

Tags: package, openmp, rcpp

I have done my first project in Rcpp recently. I prepared a Rcpp source code (say code_1) which works fine in my case, then I used Openmp to speed up the running time and it gives me the second code (say code_2) which works faster. But when I built my package by using the second code, I saw that the running time is same as code_1. 
In my package, I have protected any reference to OpenMP by using the following structure for header and also related portions of the code:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
// related commands
#endif
```

Indeed, I modified the `Makevar`file as below according to this link
[R package with C/C++ and openMP: how to make "Makevars" file under "mypackage/src/" folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974568/r-package-with-c-c-and-openmp-how-to-make-makevars-file-under-mypackage-sr):

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

I don't know how I can decrease the running time in the package similar to my second source code. Who has any experience in this case?

Comment: @coatless I have modified my makevars file by using your mentioned link and especially by using the answer by Dirk Eddelbuettel